# Better way to reformat a complex textual date string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My CMS doesn't allow me to reformat a date string on the back end, so I'm converting the text on the front end with Javascript.

This are some examples of what the CMS produces:

1. `Sunday, November 11, 2012, 4:45 PM - 6:00 PM`
2. `Every Sunday , 9:15 AM - 10:30 AM`
3. `First Sunday of the month, 9:15 AM - 1:00 PM - Rm 306`
4. `Every Wednesday, 5:30 PM - 8:30 PM, from 09/05/2012 to 11/14/2012`

Here's how I want it to be formatted:

1. `Sun, Nov 11 @ 4:45-6p` *(Short day & month name, no year, no trailing :00)*
2. `Every Sun @ 9:15-10:30a` *(no AM/PM indicator on the first time if they're both AM or PM)*
3. `First Sun of the month @ 9:15a-1p` *(Lowercase A & P)*
4. `Every Wed @ 5:30-8:30p, Sep 5-Nov 14` *(Show months on date span, remove year, remove leading 0 on dates)*

So here's the function I've come up with:

```
$(".smart-time").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html()
        .replace(/( *)?-( *)?([0-9]([0-2])?:[0-5][0-9])/gi,"-$3") // Remove space in dashes between time
        .replace(/(:[0-5][0-9])([ ]?AM)/gi,"$1a") // Short AM
        .replace(/(:[0-5][0-9])([ ]?PM)/gi,"$1p") // Short PM
        .replace(/12:00( )?p/gi,"Noon") // 12:00p = Noon
        .replace(/12:00( )?a/gi,"Midnight") // 12:00a = Midnight
        .replace(/(:00| from)/gi,"") // No trailing :00
        .replace(/([0-9:]*)a-([0-9:]*)a/gi,"$1-$2a") // Remove first 'a' in span
        .replace(/([0-9:]*)p-([0-9:]*)p/gi,"$1-$2p") // Remove first 'p' in span
        .replace(/(\, |\/)(20[0-9][0-9])/gi,"") // Remove Year
        .replace(/ to /gi,"-") // to changed to -
        .replace(/\/(0)?([0-9]*)/gi,"/$2") // Remove leading 0 in dates
        .replace(/01\//gi,"Jan ") // Change month number to short name
        .replace(/02\//gi,"Feb ")
        .replace(/03\//gi,"Mar ")
        .replace(/04\//gi,"Apr ")
        .replace(/05\//gi,"May ")
        .replace(/06\//gi,"Jun ")
        .replace(/07\//gi,"Jul ")
        .replace(/08\//gi,"Aug ")
        .replace(/09\//gi,"Sep ")
        .replace(/10\//gi,"Oct ")
        .replace(/11\//gi,"Nov ")
        .replace(/12\//gi,"Dec ")
        .replace(/(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)(s|nes|rs|ur)?day/gi,"$1") // Shorten Day names
        .replace(/\, <\/span>/gi," @ </span>") // Change , to @
        .replace(/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)((r)?uary|(t)?(em)?(o)?ber|ch|il|e|y|ust)?/gi,"$1") // Shorten Month names
    );
});
```

This works, but it feels very... bulky.

Is there a better way to do this or a simpler way to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle showing what the script does better: http://jsfiddle.net/ES4aC/1/

Comment: Indeed, human language is bulky, so bulky code is required :D

Comment: You might want to use a library that already does most of this like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com)

Comment: @epascarello May be worth using a library, however since I only need it to convert these specific dates it seems wasteful (bandwidth & resource wise) to pull in a whole library for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option worth considering is the jQuery UI Datepicker's `parseDate()` method, documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.parseDate).

However, while this is very easy to use, it's clearly only practical if you're already using datepicker on your site.

Comment: I have jQuery, but not jQuery UI. Not sure if pulling that in just for this would be worthwhile.

Comment: Yep, it almost definitely wouldn't be worth it. The library can be quite heavy in its current incarnation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not opposed to bringing in libraries, I'd take a look at [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/)

It has a number of very nice date formatting features.

From the [getting started page](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/):

```
// Lets start simple. "Today"
Date.parse('today');

// How about tomorrow?
Date.parse('tomorrow');

// July 8?
Date.parse('July 8');

// With a year?
Date.parse('July 8th, 2007');

// And time?
Date.parse('July 8th, 2007, 10:30 PM');

// Get the date, move to Monday (if not already Monday),
// then alert the date to the user in a different format.
var d1 = Date.parse('8-Jul-2007');
if (!d1.is().monday()) {
    d1.last().monday();
}
alert(d1.toString('dddd, MMMM d, yyyy'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to Date.parseDate.  Here's a good example article:
http://www.xaprb.com/articles/javascript-date-parsing-demo.html